# Как добавить столбец с указанием уже существующего столбца с ошибкой в pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by

Подскажите как решить задачу. Есть таблица pandas:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'name':[ 'A',  'A',  'B',  'C', 'C'], 
'full_name':['A',  'A_23',  'B',  'C', 'C_2'], 
'a1':[ 20,2,0,4,5],
'a2':[ 2,0,3,4,0],
'b1':[ 1,2,0,4,5],
'b2':[ 1,0,3,4,0],
'b3':[ 1,2,3,0,0]
     })
```

Где `A,B,C` - основной элемент, а `A_23` и `C_2` - дочерние. Необходимо проверить что для всех дочерних элементов ( `A_23` и `C_2`) значения в столбцах `b1`,`b2`,`b3` = 0

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На выходе необходимо получить таблицу сгруппированную по `name` с указанием в каком именно столбце допущена ошибка у дочерних элементов, те:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нашел похожее [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734695/get-column-name-where-value-is-something-in-pandas-dataframe), но не смог реализовал код для своей задачи.

Comment: может ли быть дочерних строк больше одной для одного "name"?

Comment: @MaxU да дочерних строк может быть до 6.

Comment: Хорошо бы отразить это в примерах входных и выходных данных